# Connect to localhost between containers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have 2 simple node.js apps

**app1/index.js**

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    fetch("http://localhost:3002/", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ "msg": "hello app2" })
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => {
            res.json(resp)
        })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app1 listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

**app2/index.js**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3002

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ "msg": "hello to you too" })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app2 listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

when I go to localhost:3000 on my browser the `app1` retrieves data from `app2` and displays it and this works fine locally.  The issue arises when I try to dockerize them

**Dockerfile(s) for both**

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm i

EXPOSE 3000
# EXPOSE 3002 for app2


CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    container_name: app1_c
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

  app2:
    build: ./app2
    container_name: app2_c
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

This doesn't work & the `app1` can't seem to access `app2`'s localhost:3002
I'm guessing because `app1` is sending the fetch request to it's own container's localhost:30002 instead of the app2's localhost but I thought `"host.docker.internal:host-gateway"` fixes that issue and allows cross container communication?

Could someone please help me understand?

**System Info**
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Docker Engine v24.0.6

**Edit:** Changed names `client -> app1` & `server -> app2` to avoid confusion

Comment: When running in containers, the client will need to hit `http://server:3002` (or `http://server_c:3002`. This is most easily controlled using environment variables

Comment: @Phil I'll give it a try but meanwhile is there no way to do it directly via localhost?

Comment: Consider what `localhost` is inside the container and you'll see why that is not possible

Comment: @cak3_lover You should not hard code server urls. Those should be passed using environment variables. You can change environment variables in docker. So, your code will be reusable. Same code will work in many environment without changing actual code.

Comment: @Phil, can you please reopen this? The question you've linked talks about communication between 2 containers. This question is about communication from a browser to a container.

Comment: @HansKilian no it's not!

Comment: @Phil, yes it is. The client code runs in a browser. Not in a container.

Comment: @HansKilian the code in snippet 1 makes a **server-side** request to the `server` service. You can clearly see it's Express code

Comment: @HansKilian no actually Phil is right it's between clients, I got the solution I'm editing it into the question now

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I missed that the client was a node app :(

Comment: @Phil I've edited in a solution, Is this what you meant?

Comment: @cak3_lover bingo! You might also want a default value in case the env var isn't set. But solutions shouldn't go in the question. Since this has been re-opened, you might as well self-answer it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Phil's comment I've used environment variables and changed the `app1` to as such:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import express from 'express'
import 'dotenv/config'

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    fetch(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
       body: JSON.stringify({ "msg": "hello app2" })
    })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => {
            res.json(resp)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.json({ error: "could not reach app2" })
        })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app1 listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

`.env` file contains localhost for local development:

```
CONNECTION_URL="http://localhost:3002/"
```

and in the docker-compose.yaml `environment` for production use:

```
services:
  app1:
    build: ./app1
    container_name: app1_c
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - "CONNECTION_URL=http://app2:3002"
  
  app2:
    build: ./app2
    container_name: app2_c
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
```

This seems to work, but I'm leaving the question open for accepting another answer incase there's a better way to do this in general

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer

Answer (score -2):

If you insist on having `app1` and `app2` to connect via `localhost`, you could start a container that [runs processes for both apps](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/), instead of using Docker Compose.

In the root folder, place this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN cd ./app1 && npm i && cd -

RUN cd ./app2 && npm i && cd -

EXPOSE 3002
EXPOSE 3000

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "wrapper_script.sh"]
CMD ./wrapper_script.sh
```

and this `wrapper_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

node app2/index.js & CONNECTION_URL="http://localhost:3002/" node app1/index.js

wait -n

exit $?
```

And make sure to expose 2 ports during `docker run`

Comment: What will happen if app2 crashes for some reason?  How will you figure out which logs go with which process?  This doesn't seem like a particularly robust solution, especially when the problem is a misconfigured URL.